# How to get background color of JPanel

Tags: java, swing, awt

I am trying to implement ***Connected Component Labeling*** algorithm using java swing library.

First, my code reads any B/W image from computer. Then, it iterates through image pixels `(x,y)` and returns specified pixel color.

The new image will be drawn on a `JPanel`. using `Graphics` library.

The code to draw a pixel is: `g.fillRect(x, y, width, height);`

The problem is that I am willing to get background color of the `JPanel` that I am drawing on it in order to fully implement this algorithm.

Comment: `getBackground()`?

Comment: No, i use `getRGB()` for the image. but I do not know how should i get `JPanel` color

Comment: get screenshot the panel and convert it to a image and use getRGB() to get color of any pixel that you want. And also you can check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22839618/how-to-get-pixel-color-from-graphics-g